# Django ORM: How can I sort by date and then select the best of the objects grouped by a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search, django-orm

I realize my title is kind of complex, but please allow me to demonstrate. I'm on Django 2.2.5 with Python 3. Here are the models I'm currently working with:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    _search_vector = SearchVector('thread__type') + \
                     SearchVector('thread__title') + \
                     SearchVector('from_name') + \
                     SearchVector('from_email') + \
                     SearchVector('message')

    ###
    # There's code here that updates the `Post.search_vector` field for each `Post` object
    # using `PostQuerySet._search_vector`.
    ###

    def search(self, text):
        """
            Search posts using the indexed `search_vector` field. I can, for example, call
            `Post.objects.search('influenza h1n1')`.
        """
        search_query = SearchQuery(text)
        search_rank = SearchRank(F('search_vector'), search_query)
        return self.annotate(rank=search_rank).filter(search_vector=search_query).order_by('-rank')

class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    from_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    from_email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()
    in_response_to = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    objects = PostQuerySet().as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp']
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['search_vector'])
        ]
```

(There's some stuff in these models I've cut for brevity and what I believe is irrelevance, but if it becomes important later on, I'll add it in.)

In English, I'm working with an app that represents the data in an email listserv. Basically, there's a `Thread` that contains multiple `Post` objects; people reply-all to the initial post and create a discussion. I've just finished implementing a search capability using the built-in support Django offers for full-text search in Django. It's super fast, and I love it. Here's an example of me searching in `views.py`:

```py
###
# Pull `query` from a form defined in `forms.py`.
###

search_results = Post.objects.search(query).order_by('-timestamp')
```

This is all fine and dandy and returns search results that definitely make sense. But I've just encountered a situation I'm not quite sure how to handle. The displayed results just aren't quite as clean as I'd like. What this query gets me is all `Post` objects that match the user-provided `query`. That's fine, but there may be many `Post` objects within the same `Thread` that clog up the results. It might be something like this:

```
post5 from thread2 - timestamp 2018-04-01, rank 0.5
post1 from thread3 - timestamp 2018-03-01, rank 0.25
post3 from thread2 - timestamp 2018-02-01, rank 0.75
post3 from thread1 - timestamp 2018-01-01, rank 0.6
post2 from thread1 - timestamp 2017-12-01, rank 0.7
post2 from thread2 - timestamp 2017-11-01, rank 0.7
```

(Here, `rank` is the relevance returned by Django's `SearchRank` method.)

What I really want is this: I want to display the most representative matching `Post` for each `Thread`, sorted by descending timestamp. In other words, for each `Thread` containing a `Post` in the search results, only the highest `rank` `Post` should be displayed, and those highest `rank` `Post` objects should be sorted by timestamp in descending order. So in the above example, these are the results I'd like to see:

```
post1 from thread3 - timestamp 2018-03-01, rank 0.25
post3 from thread2 - timestamp 2018-02-01, rank 0.75
post2 from thread1 - timestamp 2017-12-01, rank 0.7
```

It would be fairly straightforward to do what I want to do with a few `for` loops, but I'm really hoping there's a way to accomplish this purely in the ORM for efficiency. Do any of you guys have any suggestions? Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything about the problem setup or what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to query the **Post** model ordering it by **thread**, **rank** and **timestamp** and then use `distinct` on **thread**.

### Search

This is your search sorted by timestamp:

```py
Post.objects.search("text").order_by("-timestamp")
```

this is the SQL executed on my local PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT
    "post"."from_name",
    "thread"."title",
    "post"."timestamp",
    ts_rank("post"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('text')) AS "rank"
FROM
    "post"
    INNER JOIN "thread" ON ("post"."thread_id" = "thread"."id")
WHERE
    "post"."search_vector" @@ (plainto_tsquery('dolor')) = TRUE
ORDER BY
    "post"."timestamp" DESC
```

and these are the search results with my local data:

```
post1 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-07-01, rank 0.0607927
post2 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-06-01, rank 0.0759909
post1 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-06-01, rank 0.0759909
post2 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-05-01, rank 0.0607927
post3 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-05-01, rank 0.0607927
post1 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-05-01, rank 0.0607927
post3 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-04-01, rank 0.0759909
post4 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-04-01, rank 0.0759909
post2 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-04-01, rank 0.0759909
post5 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-03-01, rank 0.0607927
post3 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-03-01, rank 0.0607927
post4 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-03-01, rank 0.0607927
post5 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-02-01, rank 0.0759909
post4 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-02-01, rank 0.0759909
post5 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-01-01, rank 0.0759909
```

### Solution

This is the correct query to display only the most representative matching Post  (based on the search rank) for each Thread, sorted by descending timestamp

> ```py
> Post.objects.search("text").order_by(
>    "thread", "-rank", "-timestamp"
> ).distinct("thread")
> ```

this is the SQL executed on my local PostgreSQL:

> ```sql
> SELECT DISTINCT ON ("forum_post"."thread_id")
>     "forum_post"."from_name",
>     "forum_thread"."title",
>     "forum_post"."timestamp",
>     ts_rank("forum_post"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('dolor')) AS "rank"
> FROM
>     "forum_post"
>     INNER JOIN "forum_thread" ON ("forum_post"."thread_id" = "forum_thread"."id")
> WHERE
>     "forum_post"."search_vector" @@ (plainto_tsquery('dolor')) = TRUE
> ORDER BY
>     "forum_post"."thread_id" ASC,
>     "rank" DESC,
>     "forum_post"."timestamp" DESC
> ```

and these are the search results with my local data:

> ```
> post2 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-06-01, rank 0.0759909
> post1 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-06-01, rank 0.0759909
> post2 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-04-01, rank 0.0759909
> ```

### Note

You can read more about [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) on the official Django documentation.

### Update

If you need absolutely order by timestamp in reverse order and if you don't need to display the rank, you can use subquery to order your posts after the previous query:

> ```py
> Post.objects.filter(
>     pk__in=Subquery(
>         Post.objects.search("dolor")
>         .order_by("-thread", "-rank", "-timestamp")
>         .distinct("thread")
>         .values("id")
>     )
> ).order_by("-timestamp")
> ```

this is the SQL executed on my local PostgreSQL:

> ```sql
> SELECT
>     "forum_post"."from_name",
>     "forum_thread"."title",
>     "forum_post"."timestamp"
> FROM
>     "forum_post"
>     INNER JOIN "forum_thread" ON ("forum_post"."thread_id" = "forum_thread"."id")
> WHERE
>     "forum_post"."id" IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0. "thread_id")
>             U0. "id"
>         FROM
>             "forum_post" U0
>         WHERE
>             U0. "search_vector" @@ (plainto_tsquery('dolor')) = TRUE
>         ORDER BY
>             U0. "thread_id" DESC,
>             ts_rank(U0. "search_vector", plainto_tsquery('dolor'))
>             DESC,
>             U0. "timestamp" DESC)
> ORDER BY
>     "forum_post"."timestamp" DESC
> ```

and these are the search results with my local data:

> ```
> post2 from thread1 - timestamp 2019-06-01
> post1 from thread2 - timestamp 2019-06-01
> post2 from thread3 - timestamp 2019-04-01
> ```

Comment: Your method seems really close to what I need! However, because it first orders on the thread pk (where lower thread pks are for older threads), I'm not seeing the descending ordering by post timestamp unfortunately. I can sort by `-thread`, which is quite a bit closer, but it's still not quite perfect because it's still just sorting based on the thread pk, whereas the timestamp for a post within thread 12 may be after the timestamp for a post within thread 13.

Comment: @Geoff I updated my answer with a more specific solution.

Comment: Perfect! Every day, I learn something new that Django can do. That `Subquery` change is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Geoff I'm happy you found my solution useful. If you're interested in knowing more about Subquery you can read an article I wrote about it https://www.paulox.net/2018/10/01/updating-a-django-queryset-with-annotation-and-subquery/

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use `distinct` to select only first row in group of results.

Can you try something like this:

```py
results = Thread.objects.filter(post__search_vector=search_query) \
    .annotate(rank=search_rank) \
    .order_by('id', '-rank') \
    .distinct('id')

# Then sort these **limited results** by rank manually in python instead of by thread id
# The performance of this should be much better than looping over all results in Python
```

I am unable to test it as I don't have required Django models setup in place. Please share the output of `print(results.query)` for above.

Comment: I think this is an interesting take, but performing the query on the threads kinda complicates things since the `search_vector` is attached to `Post` objects, and this isn't a completely ORM-based solution. But I appreciate the thought!